# Matplotlib does not free up RAM memory after closing a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm coding a Python script which makes many plots. These plots are called from a main program which calls them recursively (by this, I mean hundreds of times).

As the main function runs, I see how my computer's RAM memory fills up during the execution. Furthermore, even after the main function finishes, the RAM memory usage is still much much higher than before the main program execution. Sometimes it can even completely fill the RAM memory.

I tried to delete the heaviest variables and use garbage collector but the net RAM memory usage is always higher. Why this is happening?

I attached a simple (and exaggerated) example of one of my functions and I used memory profiler to see line-by-line the memory usage.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    15  100.926 MiB  100.926 MiB           1   @profile
    16                                         def my_func():
    17  108.559 MiB    7.633 MiB           1    a = [1] * (10 ** 6)
    18  261.148 MiB  152.590 MiB           1    b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    19  421.367 MiB  160.219 MiB           1    c = a + b
    20  428.609 MiB    7.242 MiB           1    plt.figure(dpi=10000)
    21  430.328 MiB    1.719 MiB           1    plt.plot(np.random.rand(1000),np.random.rand(1000))
    22  487.738 MiB   57.410 MiB           1    plt.show()
    23  487.738 MiB    0.000 MiB           1    plt.close('all')
    24  167.297 MiB -320.441 MiB           1    del a,b,c
    25  118.922 MiB  -48.375 MiB           1    print(gc.collect())
```

I tried to delete the heaviest variables and use garbage collector but the net RAM memory usage is always higher.

Comment: so why are you creating `a` and `b`? It doesn't look like you use it anywhere in your code. Granted `a` and `b` are huge if you really need that large of an array why don't you create the array with np?

Comment: @AndrewRyan. I created them to exaggerate the RAM usage. The entire code is just an example.

Comment: After spending hours debugging some pytorch code for memory leaks, I just noticed the same thing, matplotlib was the culprit - not freeing up memory when exiting a function, and requiring an explicit `plt.close("all")` in between calling my plotting functions. Kind of surprising, and odd that there isn't much discussion on this issue

Answer (score 0):

I finally know what happened. It was all about Spyder, if I execute the code with the stock python terminal there are no memory leaks.

Comment: this is a comment and not the answer in it's current form.